# ID changes on Local and Live Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following ID for a Hidden field at Local Code

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFieldForPrimaryUserId" id="**MainContent_HiddenFieldForPrimaryUserId**" value="0">
```

When I Upload the same code on the Live Test Server it's ID changes to the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFieldForPrimaryUserId" id="**ctl00_MainContent_HiddenFieldForPrimaryUserId**" value="0">
```

Please tell me the reason behind this and solution to this
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you looking at the field on server using "View Source" for your browser? ID for server controls change on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **web.config** clientIDMode setting to static: e.g.

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" clientIDMode="Static">
```

Also make sure that the Application Pool on your test server is running under .NET 4.0 as the clientIDMode web.config setting is only available in .NET 4 onwards.